# psql pg_dumpall how to dump just the missing transaction when dump was active

Tags: dump, psql, database-restore

I was migrating a cluster(severals DB) and i miss some of the transactions that occured while the dump was taking place.
Is there a way to pg_dumpall the missing transactions that occured that day only and add them to the new created DB?

I am usingserver 8.4.17.

Answer (score 2):

No, not even on a current 9.3 server.

What you appear to want is an differential logical dump, i.e. dumping a series of SQL statements that would turn DB at time "n" into the DB at time "n+1".

This isn't possible because PostgreSQL doesn't keep the information that would be required to produce it.

Tools like Londiste, Slony-I, etc use triggers to achieve this, recording the required information themselves.

In PostgreSQL 9.4 it will be possible to do something similar - you can take a dump, then get a stream of changes made since the dump from a *logical replication slot*. As far as I know nobody's written anything to turn that stream into a SQL file you can run on another server yet, though.

You could be interested in the related [BDR project for bi-direcional asynchronous multi-master replication](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BDR_User_Guide), though keep in mind that at time of writing (August 2014) it's very much still under development.

However, there is *log shipping replication* with *point-in-time recovery*. This uses a physical clone of the DB files, not a logical dump, but it's essentially a continuous incremental backup. See [the manual on warm standby](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/warm-standby.html) for details, and [continuous archiving](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html).